# Trying to bind adapter to listView and I see a blank screen on my phone

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I kind of binded an adapter to listView and I don't get any error, however, I don't see an output either.

I am a very beginner and I spent more than 3 hours experimenting with this code and couldn't come up with solution

Here is my MainActivityFragment code:

```
public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] forecastArray = {
            "String 1",
            "String 2",
            "String 3",
            "String 4",
            "String 5",
            "String 6",
            "String 7",
            "String 8",
            "String 9"

    };
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(forecastArray)
    );
    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textView, weekForecast);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView_forecast);
    lv.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}
```

Comment: show your R.layout.list_item_forecast layout code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return your inflated view.

```
 public MainActivityFragment() {
  }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         String[] forecastArray = {
            "String 1",
            "String 2",
            "String 3",
            "String 4",
            "String 5",
            "String 6",
            "String 7",
            "String 8",
            "String 9"

    };
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(forecastArray)
    );
    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textView, weekForecast);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView_forecast);
    lv.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);




       return v;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me out

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `return v;` instead of return `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);`